# Looking for demo Bookmarks/Favourites to import

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari, opera

I'm wondering if there is a tool to quickly generate a demo `bookmark.html` file with a list of common bookmarks: eg. News bookmarks, Sport, Lifestyle. I'm looking for a file which I can import to my browser for demo purposes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can export your own bookmarks by

1. Open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Select Bookmarks and then Bookmark Manager.
4. In the manager, click the "Organize" menu.
5. Select Export bookmarks.

To import your bookmarks you can then import those same bookmarks (for demo purposes) by

1. Open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Select Bookmarks and then Bookmark Manager.
4. In the manager, click the "Import Bookmarks and Settings".
5. Select the dropdown and then select the "Bookmarks HTML File".
6. Choose the file you just exported.

Comment: I'm not looking for importing/exporting my own bookmarks. I'm looking for a library/collection of bookmarks 200-300 (not mine) so I can quickly import into my browser. Eg Sport related bookmarks or News related bookmarks preferably organised in folders.

Comment: I see. It seems that you'll need to make it yourself. Possibly an opportunity here!